# How to get the regular expression matching a format?

Tags: .net, regex

I need to find out regular expression for the below. It always starts with two characters MP, then there will be two random characters and then a number of any length. Is there any tool I can use to generate a regular expression by providing some examples? Thank you!

```
Examples:
MPAA1234
MPXD876323
MPJH349
```

Comment: Afaik there is no tool, but your criteria is not that hard to pull off..

Comment: here https://regex101.com/r/L26Ljt/1

Comment: please refer - https://answers.splunk.com/answers/153171/is-there-any-online-regex-tool-to-create-regular-e.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an online regex tester to check your formula interactively :

For exemple :

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3MkDmO/1)

Hope it helps.